# New to iPhone SDK: touchesBegan not called

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I created a very very basic iPhone app with File/New Projet/View-Based application.
No NIB file there.

Here is my appDelegate

.h

```
    @interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    MyViewController *viewController;
}
```

.m

```
    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    // Override point for customization after app launch    
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

And here is my loadView method in my controller

```
 - (void)loadView {
 CGRect mainFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
 UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:mainFrame];
 contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
 self.view = contentView;
 [contentView release];
}
```

Now, in order to catch the touchesBegan event, I created a new subclass of UIView:

.h

```
@interface TouchView : UIView {
}
```

.m

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 NSLog(@"Touch detected");

}
```

and modified the second line in my loadView into this :

```
 TouchView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:mainFrame];
```

Why is touchesBegan never called?

Answer (score 3):

If you change the loadView into this:

```
TouchView *contentView = [[TouchView alloc] initWithFrame:mainFrame];
```

You should have no problem catching the touches in TouchView. In your code, you didn't create a TouchView instance, you created a UIView instance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution : touchesBegan gets called on the viewController, not on the view...

Comment: Very close.  Apparently, the UIViewController gets the touchesBegan/touchesEnded/etc messages *before* the UIView.  The UIViewController doesn't pass the message along to the UIView (by calling [super touchesBegan]) by default.  So you need to move or forward to the touches* functions *if* your UIView has a controller.  Its confusing and never been documented properly but this is traditional the cocoa way.

Comment: thats absoluting wrong buddy... it is called UIView class as well.. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesMoved:withEvent: